# Converting ls output to an integer

Tags: c++, bash, shell, unix

I would like to extract a set of 2 digit numbers from the `ls` output and be able to get the biggest and smallest numbers from it, for later usage.

I am doing this:
`ls 14_data_*.log | egrep -o '[0-9]{2,2}' | head -1}` but the output is only sometimes in an ascending order and `head`, `tail` of expectantly return wrong values. I tried converting it to an integer but hopeless.

What is returned by `ls` and how can it be handled?

Comment: What are the actual filenames `ls 14_data_*.log`  is printing  for you?

Comment: If you have unsorted data you can pipe it through `sort` before using `head`.

Comment: The output of the `ls` is
http://pastebin.com/sTcWyKYz
and the full with `| egrep -o '[0-9]{3,3}'`
http://pastebin.com/9hajXqLL
It also contains some unknown junk numbers.

Comment: `sort` worked out. Don't understand the *060*s I get in my `ls` output.

Comment: It is suggested not to parse ls output.

Comment: _06_ was coming from folder name. So I added `| xargs -n1 basename` after `ls` and the problem with extra junk numbers was solved.

Comment: Using the command in your question, there shouldn't be any directory names...

Comment: Yes you are right I simplified the command not to distract from the problem. So there was "060" in the folder name, which was being printed out also. `xargs` helped me out with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` returns a list of files and directories in the current directory.

I don't know what you are upto but here is a solution to your problem using `sort`:

Descending order:

```
ls 14_data_*.log | egrep -o '[0-9]{2}' | sort -nr
```

Ascending order:

```
ls 14_data_*.log | egrep -o '[0-9]{2}' | sort -n
```

Comment: Sort indeed worked, now left with the extra numbers I get. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think that you need to use `ls` at all here. If you're sure that your filenames don't contain newline characters, you could use this:

```
printf '%s\n' 14_data_*.log | grep -Eo '[0-9]{2}'
```

Then pipe that to `sort -n`, with `-r` to reverse the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

How I understand *what you want*: you have some files in the current directory that match the glob `14_data_[0-9][0-9].log`. And you want to extract the smallest and highest number from the glob `[0-9][0-9]`.

E.g., given the listing

```
14_data_1.log
14_data_09.log
14_data_13.log
14_data_87.log
14_data_aa.log
```

you want the numbers `09` and `87`, as min and max respectively.

Here's a simple pure Bash way to achieve this:

```
shopt -s nullglob

files=( 14_data_[0-9][0-9].log )

fnumbers=( "${files[@]#14_data_}" )
fnumbers=( "${fnumbers[@]%.log}" )

if (( ${#fnumbers[@]} == 0 )); then
    echo "No files found."
else
    printf 'min=%d\nmax=%d\n' "$((10#${numbers[0]}))" "$((10#${numbers[-1]}))"
fi
```

- `shopt -s nullglob`: make globs expand to nothing if no matches
- `files=( 14_data_[0-9][0-9].log )`: populate an array `files` with all matching files
- `fnumbers=( "${files[@]#14_data_}" )`: populate an array `fnumbers` with the fields of `files` where the leading `14_data_` is removed
- `fnumbers=( "${fnumbers[@]%.log}" )`: and remove the trailing `.log` from this array

At this point, you have an array `fnumbers` that contains (in the example case): `( 09 13 87 )`.

We finally select the first and last elements of this array to get the lowest and highest number.